# php math function

Tags: php

Is there any alternative built in function to do the same job of the follow:

```
$price = round($price,-(strlen(ceil($price))-2));
```

for example:

```
$price = 1485;
echo $price = round($price,-(strlen(ceil($price))-2));//output 1500

$price = 148;
echo $price = round($price,-(strlen(ceil($price))-2));//output 150
```

Comment: Well, you could write your own custom function doing that.

Comment: Luckily among many crappy built-in functions there's none of the type you request. So you have to write yourself if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such built-in function.

However, you might shorten the term as follows:

```
$price = round($price/100)*100;
```

Comment: not work too it returns 112500 for 112540

Comment: Your code yields 110000 in this case, but in the comment under Terry Harvey's answer you state that you'd like to yield 112600. This could be achieved by the following code:

$price = ceil($price/100)*100;

You should probably provide more examples showing what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: yes sorry not 112600 it's 112550

Comment: ok, thanks ceil($price/50)*50 that's what i was looking for, thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

You could always make your own:

```
function price($str) {
    $str = round($str,-(strlen(ceil($str))-2));
    return $str;
}

// Call function
echo price(1485);
```

Terry

Comment: this function won't work for larger numbers like 112540 return 110000
i want to get 112600 instead

Comment: The guys below me already came up with a solution to that. vvv

Answer (score 0):

You're just rounding off to nearest 50. Try this : `(round($price/50))*50`

Comment: [`float` calculations introduce inaccuracies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which is the reason they are not recommended for price calculations.

Comment: @lanzz It's just an alternative. He can write a custom function as you said, if it's really gonna involve price calculations :)

Comment: this also return 112550 for 112540

Comment: @zander your answer is so close but with a small edit, this function rounding off to nearest, no matter bigger or smaller from original, i want it to round just to the larger,

Comment: @zander for example for 26766 it return 26750 when what I want is 26800

Comment: It is dangerous to encourage `float` price calculations, even as alternatives.

Comment: thanks for advice lanzz, anyway ceil($price/50)*50 is ok and do exactly what I need, thanks